# Why the internet is in use while nothing is running but Ubuntu OS?

Tags: networking, system-monitor

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and for some reasons installed it fresh yesterday , I found strange thing is happening while all my programs closed and even after turn on without open anything but system monitor I found that the internet is in use and counting bytes by it's self.
I made sure that every thing such as Connectivity Checking , problem reporting or anything is off.
So I like to know why it is counting? and what is using the internet?
[image: system-monitor-screenshot]

**update for** `sudo lsof -i`

```
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r 420 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  19717      0t0  UDP localhost:domain 
systemd-r 420 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  19718      0t0  TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
avahi-dae 762           avahi   12u  IPv4  22698      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
avahi-dae 762           avahi   13u  IPv6  22699      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
avahi-dae 762           avahi   14u  IPv4  22700      0t0  UDP *:35159 
avahi-dae 762           avahi   15u  IPv6  22701      0t0  UDP *:50757 
cupsd     804            root    6u  IPv6  23689      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd     804            root    7u  IPv4  23690      0t0  TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
cups-brow 810            root    7u  IPv4  23703      0t0  UDP *:ipp 
dhclient  907            root    6u  IPv4  24789      0t0  UDP *:bootpc
```

[image: sudo lsof -i screenshot]

**update for** `ps aux`  UPDATED

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2 160172  9408 ?        Ss   12:54   0:06 /sbin/init spla
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root        10  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        I    12:54   0:20 [rcu_sched]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [migration/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [idle_inject/0]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [idle_inject/1]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [migration/1]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [kworker/1:0H-k
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [netns]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [rcu_tasks_kthr
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [kauditd]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [oom_reaper]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [writeback]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [kcompactd0]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   12:54   0:00 [ksmd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   12:54   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [kblockd]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [blkcg_punt_bio
root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [tpm_dev_wq]
root        81  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [md]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [edac-poller]
root        84  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [watchdogd]
root        87  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        88  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthre
root        90  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        91  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [acpi_thermal_p
root        92  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        95  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root        97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [vfio-irqfd-cle
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root       108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [kstrp]
root       111  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [kworker/u9:0]
root       125  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [charger_manage
root       127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:02 [kworker/1:1H-e
root       168  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:05 [kworker/0:1H-e
root       197  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:54   0:01 [jbd2/sda5-8]
root       198  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   12:54   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conve
root       241  0.0  0.9 141668 39748 ?        S<s  12:54   0:01 /lib/systemd/sy
root       264  0.0  0.1  48008  6180 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop0]
root       268  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop1]
root       270  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop2]
root       272  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop3]
root       274  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop4]
root       276  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop5]
root       278  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop6]
root       280  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop7]
root       282  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop8]
root       284  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop9]
root       286  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop10]
root       288  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop11]
root       290  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop12]
root       292  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop13]
root       294  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop14]
root       296  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop15]
root       298  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop16]
root       300  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop17]
root       307  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop18]
root       310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:54   0:00 [loop19]
systemd+   608  0.0  0.1  70884  6076 ?        Ss   12:54   0:01 /lib/systemd/sy
systemd+   609  0.0  0.0 145964  3232 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
message+   763  0.0  0.1  51500  5920 ?        Rs   12:54   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
root       772  0.0  0.4 480772 16588 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/Netwo
avahi      774  0.0  0.0  47260  3264 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 avahi-daemon: r
root       776  0.0  0.0   4556   792 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root       779  0.0  0.4 170536 17300 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python
root       780  0.0  0.3 503640 12164 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:01 /usr/lib/udisks
root       782  0.0  0.1  45236  5364 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /sbin/wpa_suppl
root       785  0.0  0.2 100604  8168 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd
root       786  0.0  0.0 110420  2052 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqba
root       790  0.0  0.0  31328  3288 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron 
root       791  0.0  0.1 287656  7008 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/lib/accoun
root       810  0.0  0.2 360600  9656 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/Modem
syslog     811  0.0  0.1 263040  4696 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsysl
root       815  0.0  0.7 1090380 31188 ?       Ssl  12:54   0:03 /usr/lib/snapd/
root       816  0.0  0.1  70580  6072 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
kernoops   825  0.0  0.0  56944  2584 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/kerne
kernoops   827  0.0  0.0  56944  2516 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/kerne
avahi      828  0.0  0.0  47080   336 ?        S    12:54   0:00 avahi-daemon: c
root       829  0.0  0.2 303668 11232 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-
root       849  0.0  0.2 292988  8800 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
root       878  0.0  0.5 187244 20060 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python
root       883  0.0  0.1 301088  7976 ?        Ssl  12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
root       892  0.0  0.2 254452  8416 ?        Sl   12:54   0:00 gdm-session-wor
root       915  0.0  0.1  25988  6496 ?        S    12:54   0:00 /sbin/dhclient 
gdm        916  0.0  0.1  76888  7956 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
gdm        917  0.0  0.0 114108  2704 ?        S    12:54   0:00 (sd-pam)
gdm        961  0.0  0.1 190696  5532 tty1     Ssl+ 12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/g
gdm        963  0.0  0.1  50228  4748 ?        Ss   12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
gdm        966  0.0  0.3 625408 13832 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm        999  0.0  3.2 3383724 130024 tty1   Sl+  12:55   0:06 /usr/bin/gnome-
root      1007  0.0  0.2 315240  8384 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/upower
gdm       1057  0.0  1.4 885884 59912 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/Xwayla
gdm       1069  0.0  0.1 349244  6224 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
gdm       1074  0.0  0.0  49932  3780 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
gdm       1076  0.0  0.1 220768  7052 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
gdm       1080  0.0  0.4 1317604 16016 ?       Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/pulsea
rtkit     1081  0.0  0.0 183512  2932 ?        SNsl 12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/
gdm       1095  0.0  0.1 427996  7912 tty1     Sl   12:55   0:00 ibus-daemon --x
gdm       1098  0.0  0.1 273644  5848 tty1     Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
gdm       1101  0.0  0.7 707476 30252 tty1     Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
gdm       1103  0.0  0.1 271456  5948 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
root      1116  0.0  0.1 289772  6768 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64
root      1120  0.1  1.0 514816 41164 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:10 /usr/lib/packag
gdm       1121  0.0  0.7 857988 30920 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1125  0.0  0.1 271028  5880 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1126  0.0  0.7 707100 29804 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1129  0.0  0.7 1022088 31208 tty1    Sl+  12:55   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1130  0.0  0.3 386616 13716 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1131  0.0  0.1 276640  5320 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1134  0.0  0.7 861456 30308 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1138  0.0  0.8 1436760 32536 tty1    Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1140  0.0  0.1 194896  4528 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1141  0.0  0.7 945848 31024 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1142  0.0  0.2 259916  8796 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1145  0.0  0.1 194916  4616 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1146  0.0  0.1 268632  4736 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1148  0.0  0.2 297992  8340 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1157  0.0  0.2 370948  8048 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1158  0.0  0.2 327848  8192 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1163  0.0  0.7 791952 30728 tty1     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1173  0.0  0.1 197788  5960 tty1     Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
colord    1245  0.0  0.3 317872 13620 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/colord
root      1266  0.0  0.2 260640  8620 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 gdm-session-wor
mr-bass+  1272  0.0  0.2  77096  8212 ?        Ss   12:55   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
mr-bass+  1273  0.0  0.0 114108  2708 ?        S    12:55   0:00 (sd-pam)
mr-bass+  1286  0.0  0.1 281272  7696 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
mr-bass+  1290  0.0  0.1 205032  5904 tty2     Ssl+ 12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/g
mr-bass+  1292  5.6  1.3 947076 52468 tty2     Sl+  12:55   9:13 /usr/lib/xorg/X
mr-bass+  1306  0.0  0.1  51008  5388 ?        Ss   12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
mr-bass+  1309  0.0  0.3 551948 13940 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1404  0.0  0.0  11312   316 ?        Ss   12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-ag
mr-bass+  1410  0.0  0.1 349272  6076 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
mr-bass+  1415  0.0  0.1  49932  4432 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
mr-bass+  1417  0.0  0.1 220780  6892 ?        Sl   12:55   0:01 /usr/lib/at-spi
mr-bass+  1438  4.0  4.7 3447008 191128 tty2   Sl+  12:55   6:32 /usr/bin/gnome-
mr-bass+  1448  0.0  0.1 358732  7332 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1453  0.0  0.1 416116  5440 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1464  2.0  0.4 1334616 17432 ?       S<l  12:55   3:14 /usr/bin/pulsea
mr-bass+  1477  0.0  0.2 354624  8004 tty2     Sl   12:55   0:02 ibus-daemon --x
mr-bass+  1481  0.0  0.1 273652  6772 tty2     Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
mr-bass+  1483  0.0  0.5 336820 20844 tty2     Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
mr-bass+  1487  0.0  0.1 271456  6040 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
mr-bass+  1496  0.0  0.5 691080 22260 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1502  0.0  0.6 1102904 26212 ?       Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
mr-bass+  1511  0.0  0.2 373192  9260 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1515  0.0  0.1 268768  4868 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1519  0.0  0.1 371728  7744 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1524  0.0  0.1 266944  6028 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1528  0.0  0.8 783848 33548 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1538  0.0  0.1 369992  7864 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1544  0.0  0.1 281688  6640 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1550  0.0  0.5 509892 21760 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1553  0.0  0.2 342232 10224 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1554  0.0  0.1 416244  5892 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1555  0.0  0.1 268632  5784 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1558  0.0  0.2 445724  9148 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1560  0.0  0.2 444676  8048 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1563  0.0  0.2 327860  8092 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1565  0.0  0.5 487348 21768 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1575  0.0  0.5 421260 20860 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1579  0.0  0.1 271028  5904 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1580  0.0  0.5 336456 20208 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1581  0.0  0.3 462620 13884 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1584  0.0  0.1 357324  7028 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1586  0.0  0.5 651412 21652 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1589  0.0  0.5 861544 23260 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1592  0.0  0.1 271036  5876 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1594  0.0  0.5 499260 21392 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1614  0.0  0.3 501676 12648 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1646  0.0  0.1 271936  6396 tty2     Sl+  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  1647  0.0  1.9 1027312 76020 tty2    Sl+  12:55   0:03 nautilus-deskto
mr-bass+  1663  0.0  1.6 885512 67436 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
mr-bass+  1666  0.0  0.1 361140  7604 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1682  0.0  0.1 197788  6760 tty2     Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
mr-bass+  1694  0.0  1.5 1129300 62752 ?       Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
mr-bass+  1696  0.0  0.1 188036  5384 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/
mr-bass+  1699  0.0  0.1 358604  6248 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  1712  0.0  0.6 725588 24104 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
mr-bass+  1725  0.0  0.6 1075636 26304 ?       Sl   12:55   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
mr-bass+  1759  0.0  3.1 1331384 127148 tty2   SLl+ 12:56   0:04 /usr/bin/gnome-
mr-bass+  1761  0.0  0.6 663440 27156 tty2     Sl+  12:56   0:00 update-notifier
mr-bass+  1866  0.0  0.1 197404  5920 ?        Ssl  12:57   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      1908  5.9  0.0      0     0 ?        I    13:01   9:21 [kworker/1:1-ev
root      2339  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   13:07   0:00 [loop20]
root      3470  2.9  0.0      0     0 ?        I    13:27   3:52 [kworker/0:0-ev
mr-bass+  3494  0.0  0.5 400972 21092 ?        Sl   13:30   0:00 /usr/bin/snap u
mr-bass+  3511  0.0  0.2 352540 10312 ?        Sl   13:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
mr-bass+  5159  0.0  0.1 363264  7512 ?        Sl   14:19   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      5218  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   14:19   0:00 [kworker/0:2H]
mr-bass+  5223  0.0  0.1 374192  7344 ?        Sl   14:19   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      5402  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:32   0:02 [kworker/u8:0-e
root      5864  1.1  0.0      0     0 ?        I    15:04   0:22 [kworker/1:2-ev
root      5961  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    15:24   0:00 [kworker/u8:3+e
root      5973  1.1  0.0      0     0 ?        I    15:25   0:08 [kworker/0:1-ev
root      6159  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    15:31   0:00 [kworker/u8:2-i
root      6165  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    15:32   0:00 [kworker/1:3-ev
mr-bass+  6185  3.9  1.1 649604 44024 tty2     Sl+  15:37   0:01 gnome-system-mo
mr-bass+  6196  6.5  1.2 1202584 50920 ?       Sl   15:37   0:01 /usr/bin/nautil
root      6210  0.0  0.0  61692  2784 ?        Ss   15:37   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
mr-bass+  6229  8.5  0.9 794348 36684 ?        Ssl  15:37   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
mr-bass+  6238  0.7  0.1  22456  4532 pts/0    Ss   15:37   0:00 bash
mr-bass+  6246  0.0  0.0  39672  3604 pts/0    R+   15:37   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `ps aux`

Comment: `sudo lsof -i` will show the internet connections. Read `man lsof`.

Comment: I updated the question and added screenshots for the result of commands.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I see 3 possibly 4 items that can communicate to the internet that run in the background.  Avahi, CUPS and dhclient.  The other possible one is Evolution email application.  Plus, DNS, DHCP etc are always communicating if you have an active network connection.

Comment: Okay thanks for reply , all are in codes now.

Comment: Ubuntu on Wayland the best way for now as I found , and the question will be open if any other person found another way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use Ubuntu on Wayland that used about 1.5 megabyte when the system on and partitions open, then almost all the time that no programs are using the internet it will be 0 receiving or sending as it should to be, but when you try to do offline activities as open partitions or anything else it will send few KB about it, I removed the Evolution files from system by `sudo rm -R` but it still the same and the result of `sudo ps aux` updated today 25-10-2021.

[image]

[image]

The same with Ubuntu "normal log in" I haven't found any thing strange was running, all about system files, if I tried to remove xorg , Kworkers or any file system the system will fail, I turned off the daily auto check for update and all the options of privacy turned off, but it was still fishy and unstable, the few KB or megabytes anyway not a problem for the internet capacity, the problem is if you haven't turned on your privacy option to allow it to send about programs you are using or your activities on your operation system it Shouldn't send about anything.

[image]

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.5  0.2 159828  9048 ?        Ss   08:43   0:01 /sbin/init spla
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/0:0-ev
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kworker/0:0H-k
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    08:43   0:00 [kworker/u8:0+e
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root        10  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [migration/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [idle_inject/0]
root        13  1.2  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:03 [kworker/0:1-ev
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [idle_inject/1]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [migration/1]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/1:0-ev
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kworker/1:0H-k
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [netns]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [rcu_tasks_kthr
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [kauditd]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [oom_reaper]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [writeback]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [kcompactd0]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   08:43   0:00 [ksmd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   08:43   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/1:1-ev
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kblockd]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [blkcg_punt_bio
root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [tpm_dev_wq]
root        81  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [md]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [edac-poller]
root        84  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [watchdogd]
root        86  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/u8:1-e
root        87  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        88  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthre
root        90  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        91  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [acpi_thermal_p
root        92  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        95  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root        96  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/u8:2-e
root        97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [vfio-irqfd-cle
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root        99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/u8:3-e
root       108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kstrp]
root       111  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kworker/u9:0]
root       124  1.2  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:03 [kworker/1:2-cg
root       125  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [charger_manage
root       126  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/u8:4-e
root       127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/u8:5-i
root       128  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kworker/0:1H-e
root       129  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/0:2-ev
root       130  0.5  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:01 [kworker/1:3-ev
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:43   0:00 [kworker/0:3-ev
root       195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [kworker/1:1H-e
root       198  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:43   0:00 [jbd2/sda6-8]
root       199  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   08:43   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conve
root       241  0.1  0.7 103196 30772 ?        S<s  08:44   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       264  0.3  0.1  48172  6444 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop0]
root       269  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop1]
root       270  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop2]
root       272  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop3]
root       274  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop4]
root       276  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop5]
root       279  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop6]
root       280  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop7]
root       282  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop8]
root       284  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop9]
root       287  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop10]
root       289  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop11]
root       290  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop12]
root       297  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop13]
root       302  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop14]
root       304  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop15]
root       306  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop16]
root       309  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop17]
root       310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop18]
root       313  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   08:44   0:00 [loop19]
systemd+   456  0.0  0.1  70492  4780 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       504  0.5  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:44   0:01 [kworker/1:4-ev
root       714  0.0  0.2 434328  9640 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/Modem
avahi      720  0.0  0.0  47260  3288 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 avahi-daemon: r
message+   721  0.2  0.1  51544  6024 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
avahi      738  0.0  0.0  47080   340 ?        S    08:44   0:00 avahi-daemon: c
root       743  0.0  0.1  70588  5972 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       744  0.0  0.1 287660  7164 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/accoun
root       746  0.0  0.0 110420  2068 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqba
root       750  0.0  0.0   4556   844 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
syslog     751  0.0  0.1 263040  4708 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsysl
root       754  0.0  0.0  31328  3332 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron 
root       759  0.0  0.4 170536 17236 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python
root       762  0.0  0.2 100876  8640 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd
root       764  0.0  0.2 503644 11844 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks
root       767  0.0  0.1  45236  5320 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /sbin/wpa_suppl
root       768  0.1  0.4 480760 16480 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/Netwo
root       769  0.8  0.9 1188708 38836 ?       Ssl  08:44   0:02 /usr/lib/snapd/
root       777  0.2  0.2 292980  8920 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
root       779  0.0  0.2 303684 10792 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-
kernoops   780  0.0  0.0  56944  2540 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/kerne
kernoops   782  0.0  0.0  56944   420 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/kerne
colord     808  0.0  0.3 317892 13700 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/colord
lp         823  0.0  0.1  86428  6012 ?        S    08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/n
lp         824  0.0  0.1  86428  6032 ?        S    08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/n
root       838  0.0  0.5 187232 20004 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python
root       843  0.0  0.1 300956  7900 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
root       848  0.0  0.2 254452  8412 ?        Sl   08:44   0:00 gdm-session-wor
gdm        879  0.0  0.2  76912  8036 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
gdm        882  0.0  0.0 113972  2608 ?        S    08:44   0:00 (sd-pam)
root       886  0.0  0.1  25988  6084 ?        S    08:44   0:00 /sbin/dhclient 
gdm        922  0.0  0.1 190696  5528 tty1     Ssl+ 08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/g
gdm        924  0.0  0.1  50228  4672 ?        Ss   08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
gdm        926  0.0  0.3 551708 13760 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm        932  1.4  3.2 3384028 129992 tty1   Sl+  08:44   0:03 /usr/bin/gnome-
root       967  0.0  0.2 315188  8564 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/upower
gdm        997  0.0  1.5 885872 60060 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/Xwayla
gdm       1008  0.0  0.1 349340  6464 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
gdm       1013  0.0  0.0  49932  3900 ?        S    08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
gdm       1015  0.0  0.1 220768  5860 ?        Sl   08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
gdm       1019  0.0  0.4 1317628 16168 ?       Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/pulsea
rtkit     1020  0.0  0.0 183512  2912 ?        SNsl 08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/
gdm       1056  0.0  0.1 428000  7804 tty1     Sl   08:44   0:00 ibus-daemon --x
gdm       1059  0.0  0.1 273644  5912 tty1     Sl   08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
gdm       1062  0.0  0.7 707480 30036 tty1     Sl   08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
gdm       1064  0.0  0.1 271588  5896 ?        Sl   08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
gdm       1073  0.0  0.1 264460  5036 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/libexec/xd
root      1081  0.0  0.1 289772  6848 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64
root      1085  4.3  1.0 514936 41916 ?        Ssl  08:44   0:09 /usr/lib/packag
gdm       1086  0.0  0.7 858056 31148 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1089  0.0  0.1 271056  5840 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1090  0.0  0.7 707128 29368 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1092  0.0  0.7 1022152 31048 tty1    Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1094  0.0  0.3 386616 13716 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1095  0.0  0.1 276640  5320 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1096  0.0  0.7 861540 30476 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1100  0.0  0.8 1150084 32788 tty1    Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1101  0.0  0.1 194896  4556 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1102  0.0  0.7 872148 31036 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1108  0.0  0.2 259916  8712 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1109  0.0  0.1 194916  4784 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1111  0.0  0.1 268632  4736 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1112  0.0  0.2 298020  8372 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1120  0.0  0.1 370964  7912 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1122  0.0  0.2 327880  8088 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1126  0.0  0.7 791980 30388 tty1     Sl+  08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
gdm       1138  0.0  0.1 197788  6420 tty1     Sl   08:44   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
root      1218  0.0  0.2 260640  8644 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 gdm-session-wor
bassem-+  1221  0.1  0.2  76980  8200 ?        Ss   08:45   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
bassem-+  1222  0.0  0.0 113972  2612 ?        S    08:45   0:00 (sd-pam)
bassem-+  1235  0.0  0.1 281252  7764 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
bassem-+  1239  0.0  0.1 190696  5564 tty2     Ssl+ 08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/g
bassem-+  1241  0.1  0.1  50844  5256 ?        Ss   08:45   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
bassem-+  1243  0.0  0.3 764972 14200 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1311 11.0  7.5 3490224 302252 tty2   Sl+  08:45   0:21 /usr/bin/gnome-
bassem-+  1325  0.0  0.1 284872  7088 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1330  0.0  0.1 416116  5428 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1338  0.3  1.7 933520 70960 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/bin/Xwayla
bassem-+  1349  0.0  0.1 349276  6324 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
bassem-+  1354  0.0  0.1  49928  4220 ?        S    08:45   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
bassem-+  1356  0.0  0.1 220768  7132 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
bassem-+  1362  0.0  0.4 1334352 16616 ?       S<l  08:45   0:00 /usr/bin/pulsea
bassem-+  1374  0.0  0.1 428068  7856 tty2     Sl   08:45   0:00 ibus-daemon --x
bassem-+  1378  0.0  0.1 273652  6692 tty2     Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
bassem-+  1379  0.0  0.1 264460  5004 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/libexec/xd
bassem-+  1385  0.0  0.7 707332 29768 tty2     Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
bassem-+  1388  0.0  0.1 271456  5976 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
bassem-+  1401  0.0  0.2 299344  8756 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1408  0.0  0.1 371728  7580 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1413  0.0  0.1 266944  6120 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1417  0.0  0.8 783876 33768 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1424  0.0  0.1 296260  7608 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1429  0.0  0.1 281696  6692 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1433  0.0  0.1 268768  5008 ?        Ssl  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1439  0.0  0.7 871992 30448 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1440  0.0  0.2 342252 10244 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1441  0.0  0.1 416244  5872 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1442  0.0  0.1 268632  4872 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1445  0.0  0.2 445752  9084 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1449  0.0  0.7 857892 30972 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1454  0.0  0.7 791792 30120 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1455  0.0  0.1 370976  7944 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1456  0.0  0.2 327884  8056 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1460  0.0  0.1 271056  5864 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1464  0.0  0.7 706948 29328 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1467  0.0  0.7 1022004 30548 tty2    Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1470  0.0  0.3 462648 13756 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1473  0.0  0.1 357360  7196 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1474  0.0  0.7 861400 30132 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1477  0.0  0.7 1436696 31876 tty2    Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1480  0.0  0.1 271064  5920 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1500  0.0  0.3 501676 12620 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1509  0.0  0.1 197788  6760 tty2     Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
bassem-+  1574  0.6  1.2 783248 51380 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:01 nautilus-deskto
bassem-+  1588  0.0  0.1 271936  6288 tty2     Sl+  08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1607  0.0  0.1 361132  7420 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1621  0.0  0.1 188032  5420 ?        Sl   08:45   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/
bassem-+  1632  0.0  0.5 643108 21120 tty2     Sl+  08:46   0:00 update-notifier
bassem-+  1634  4.2  3.9 1373584 158568 tty2   SLl+ 08:46   0:05 /usr/bin/gnome-
root      1654  0.1  0.5 565676 23288 ?        Ssl  08:46   0:00 /usr/lib/fwupd/
bassem-+  1673  0.0  0.1 488292  6004 ?        Ssl  08:46   0:00 /usr/libexec/xd
bassem-+  1771  0.0  0.2 589480  9048 ?        Ssl  08:46   0:00 /usr/libexec/xd
bassem-+  1777  0.0  0.4 468200 19552 ?        Ssl  08:46   0:00 /usr/libexec/xd
bassem-+  1843  0.0  0.1 197300  6124 ?        Ssl  08:47   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
bassem-+  1846  0.1  0.8 797224 34444 tty2     Sl+  08:47   0:00 /usr/lib/deja-d
root      1869  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    08:47   0:00 [kworker/1:5-ev
bassem-+  1877  1.0  0.9 556576 37872 ?        Rsl  08:47   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
bassem-+  1882  0.0  0.1  22448  4456 pts/0    Ss   08:47   0:00 bash
root      1895  0.1  0.1  65852  4512 pts/0    S+   08:48   0:00 sudo ps aux
root      1896  0.0  0.0  37376  3296 pts/0    R+   08:48   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: Your answer should really show the difference of both ways of logging in over a period of time.  A short period of time actually isn't very helpful as you may have hit a time that like update checks and application network checks (i.e. DHCP, DNS, etc) weren't needed at the time.  Also, in your question you have Evolution, that is an email client running, and  will check quite often for new emails.  Did you check for Evolution running when you are in Wayland?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed now about your reply, it's the same way sort of , Closed all applications , updated, privacy options, made sure after reinstalled the Operation system to choose don't send any information about my usage to Ubuntu and all things I could do, but it still following by the Internet , when you start 1.5 MB receive , few KB send , and when you open partitions few KB send, and few after it receive. I am still watching it and looking for solve, satellites is enough

Comment: Also about evolution it's a system files at /usr/lib but the program isn't installed , I used sudo apt remove evolution , the result was Package 'evolution' is not installed, so not removed  , I never used this program, using Thunderbird For mails .

Comment: Evolution and Thunderbird may rely on the same system files.  Anyways, what is your goal?  Is it to not have any network activity but still have the network connected?

Comment: Even we removed Thunderbird the evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess, evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess, evolution-source-registry will still there , so if you think it's the reason of the problem , I will Chroot and remove all it's folders from the system and watch if any thing will change, anyway it's not a high internet data that what running thing is using , but it's how you choose to cancel any option appear to let you choose share information about your computer although it happen, will try to remove folder from system files hope it will not effect and run well.

Comment: Okay It wasn't the reason I removed files , folders , and even icons from system , but it still the same when you log in or open partitions or any activities , I also update the ps aux result here in the same answer